# Clone row and point to the new row

Tags: sql

I managed to clone a row from `table_source` into `table_temp`, 
and update its field `f0`.

But how can I point to the new inserted row?

I want to insert the new inserted id from table `table_source` into the field `f_id` in `table2`:

```
INSERT into table_temp (f0, f1, f2)  
  select f0, f1, f2 from table_source   
  where . . .

UPDATE table_temp SET f0 =  'newValue'  

INSERT INTO table_source select * from table_temp  

UPDATE table2 SET f_id = ??? WHERE . . .      <- what id can I use here?

DELETE FROM table_temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scope_Identity()](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190315.aspx) returns identifier of the last inserted row within current scope. See also [@@identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187342.aspx).

Comment: To deterimine unique identifier of the last inserted row you need to have auto-increment integer column, attributed as IDENTITY, in table. After that you can use Scope_Identity() of the *last* inserted row.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin. @@identity is now 0. how do I set the field "attributed as IDENTITY" ?

Comment: @Atara ah man, i thought you're using MS SQL, not MySql. Please google for "mysql new inserted id"